# Calculator shows $-1\times -1=1$ and $-1^2=-1$, instead of the same result

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I have a question on $-1$.

If we write on Calculator as $-1 \times -1$, it will show answer $1$, Whereas if I write as $-1^2$ then it shows answer $-1$.

How is this possible? As these, both are the same things.

Comment: $(-1)(-1)$ and $-(1\cdot 1)$ are not quite the same thing

Comment: Further explanation: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/h/blaine2.html

Comment: Type in $(-1)^2$ and your doubts will be gone. In the Netherlands we have a sentence which gives the order of mathematical operations. This order is: powers - multiply - divide - squareroots - addition - subtraction (if I remember correctly). $-1^2$, you first calculate the power, and following you multiply by $-1$ ( you can make your own sentence to remember the order :P)

Comment: On my hp48, $1$, $+/-$, $x^2$ shows $1$, what is your calculator?

Comment: We understand $-a^2$ to mean $-(a^2)$,  This is because, if you want $(-a)^2$, then  you would just write $a^2$.

Comment: @GEdgar : Not necessarily. In some contexts it makes sense to write $(-a)^2. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because calculator firstly makes $1^2$ and only then puts minus. Try to write brackets $(-1)^2$ and you will have correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may think to be "$-$" an abbreviation of "$-1\cdot$". In that sense:
$$\color{red}-1^2=\color{red}{-1\cdot}1^2=-1\cdot1=-1.$$
In fact, $-1^2$ isn't a square as the name of a term, sum, product etc., comes from the *last* operation which is performed. In our case it's a multiplication (by $-1$).

Answer (score 1):

$-5^2$ means $-(5^2),$ not $(-5)^2.$

Comment: This better suits as a comment.

Comment: @SarGe : Except that it completely answers the question.

Comment: See, @Arctic Char's comment.